# Loading any persistent workflow containing delay activity when it is a runnable instance in the store

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

We are trying to load and resume workflows which have a delay. I have seen the Microsoft sample of Absolute Delay for this using store.WaitForEvents and LoadRunnableInstance to load the workflow. However here the workflow is already known.

In our case we want to have an event  waiting for the store.WaitForEvents after every say 5 seconds to check if there is a runnable instance and if so only load and run that /those particular instances. Is there a way I could know which workflow instance is ready.

We are maintaing the workflow id and the xaml associated to it in our database, so if we could know the workflow instance id we could get the xaml mapped to it, create the workflow and then do a LOadRunnableInstance on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Microsoft sample (Absolute Delay)

```
public void Run(){
    wfHostTypeName = XName.Get("Version" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
                               typeof(WorkflowWithDelay).FullName);

    this.instanceStore = SetupSqlpersistenceStore();

    this.instanceHandle = 
        CreateInstanceStoreOwnerHandle(instanceStore, wfHostTypeName);
    WorkflowApplication wfApp = CreateWorkflowApp();
    wfApp.Run();

    while (true) 
    {
        this.waitHandler.WaitOne();
        if (completed) 
        {
            break;
        }

        WaitForRunnableInstance(this.instanceHandle);
        wfApp = CreateWorkflowApp();

        try 
        {
            wfApp.LoadRunnableInstance();
            waitHandler.Reset();
            wfApp.Run();
        } 
        catch (InstanceNotReadyException) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handled expected InstanceNotReadyException, retrying...");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("workflow completed.");
}

public void WaitForRunnableInstance(InstanceHandle handle) 
{
    var events=instanceStore.WaitForEvents(handle, TimeSpan.MaxValue);
    bool foundRunnable = false;
    foreach (var persistenceEvent in events) 
    {
        if (persistenceEvent.Equals(HasRunnableWorkflowEvent.Value)) 
        {
            foundRunnable = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!foundRunnable) {
        Console.WriteLine("no runnable instance");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Anamika

Comment: I thought reloads were automatic when Delay activities expired, so long as the (service) host remained active.

Comment: The issue is when the service host is stopped and restarted again. Also it is automatic if WorkflowServiceHost is used. We are using WorkflowApplication for which we need to manually load the running instance.

Comment: Have you looked at the DurableDelay and DurableDelayXamlx samples?

Comment: The DurableDelay and DurableDelayXamlx samples use WCFServiceHost. We are handicapped in using them because our workflows would be dynamic ones created by the user and stored as xaml in the database. We have no idea of the endpoints to have a service running in WCFServiceHost

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with durable delay activities and WorkflowApplicationHost.  Ended up creating my own 'Delay' activity that worked essentially the same way as the one out of the box, (takes an arg that describes when to resume the workflow, and then bookmarks itself).  Instead of saving delay info in the SqlInstanceStore though, my Delay Activity created a record in a seperate db. (similar to the one you are using to track the Workflow Ids and Xaml).  I then wrote a simple service that polled that DB for expired delays and initiated a resume of the necessary workflow.

Oh, and the Delay activity deleted it's record from that DB on bookmark resume.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a separate SqlPersistenceStore for each workflow definition you're hosting.

Comment: Thanks for your response Joe. 
Actually we provide the option to the user to create workflows from the designer with custom activities we provide. These workflow xamls are then stored in the database and could be run thereafter.
So, there could virtually be 100s of workflows like this and I am not sure we could keep creating multiple stores for them

Comment: Got it.  Indeed WorkflowServiceHost is designed for this purpose, but it doesn't seem amenable to your workflows.  LoadRunnableInstance is only usable when you already know the workflow definition, so I imagine you'll need to find the instance ID you want to load separately.  Then you can pick the right workflow definition for initializing WorkflowApplication and run  WorkflowApplication.Load.